# Can someone please help me identify these ming dynasty coins?

Tags: identification, numismatics

It would be helpful if someone could identify these coins for me. I would primarily be interested in the size of these coins.
[image: image of three ming dynasty coins]

Comment: Where is the image from? Is it the Shanghai Museum?

Comment: @SteveBird I got the image from the internet, the link is https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Ming_Dynasty_Coins.jpg According to the description, yes, it is from the Shanghai Museum.